# I need to make a object to float left while fading out inside a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I need to float this white arrow head to right side while fading it's color.

I tried to do it this way..

```
<div onMouseOver="myfunction()" style="width:250px; height:50px; background-color:#09F;">
<img id="sliding_image" src="images/leftmenuicon.png" width="30" height="30" />
</div>
<script>
function myfunction(){
document.getElementById("sliding_image").style.paddingLeft="100px";
}
</script>
```

but i cant control the speed. when i move my mouse over that div that arrow is just popping up at next side. i don't need that. i need to see that arrow is going to the other end.

is there any jquery or javascript to do this?

Comment: Did you search for "jQuery animate"?

Comment: As @ThomasW said,You need Animate()..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you tagged jquery  ,Use `Animate()`

```
$("yourDivId").hover(function(){
    $('#sliding_image').animate({
        'padding-left': '+=100px'
    }, "normal");
}, function(){
   $('#sliding_image').animate({
        'padding-left': '-=100px'
    }, "normal");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: sir, I'm really really new to jquery 
can you please give me full example ?

Comment: Here is the API ,http://api.jquery.com/animate/   And i suggest you to start using Jquery API,which gives the benefit of **Write less,Do more**

Answer (score 0):

---

You could also do it by CSS3 animations.

Here is a great guide for that : [Using CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations)